# Figure out what is changing style attributes on website

Tags: html, css, attributes, styles, google-chrome-devtools

There is always an automatically added style attribute to nearly every single div on my site. It always looks like this `<div style="height: auto !important">`

The source code always looks fine and it only appears on the final rendered website.
How can I find out what is causing this?

With the DevTool of Google Chrome I already tried to do a "Break on attribute modification", but this did not get me any results.

As an example you can see this webpage: https://shortorial.com/quickly-fix-the-color-and-brightness-of-a-picture-in-photoshop/

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site grid-container container grid-parent" style="height: auto !important;">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" style="height: auto !important;">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area grid-parent mobile-grid-100 push-25 grid-75 tablet-push-25 tablet-grid-75" style="height: auto !important;">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" style="height: auto !important;">
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Inline styles are nearly *always* added by Javascript.

Comment: One big issue with your question is that when I first opened your page (in Brave, where AdSense was blocked) none of your divs had the extra styling. Do add some code in your next questions to help people see the issue straight away

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for your feedback (I'm new here). I updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to AdSense, or more precisely this script file loaded in your page's head which injects the style on all your div:
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20191003/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js

You can search for **e.setProperty("height","auto","important")** in the script file to find where the change is being made.

*Edit:*

If you'd like to remove the style field from all divs, you can loop through all of them using **document.getElementsByTagName**:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var item of list) {
    item.style.height="";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and the help.
I found this code and adapted it. But it is only changing the wrapper and not the sub-elements. Is there a solution to undo what Adsense is doing (for the entire page)?

`<script>
let wrapper = document.getElementById('page')
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
  wrapper.style.height = ''
  wrapper.style.minHeight = ''
})
observer.observe(wrapper, {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['style']
})
</script>`

Comment: You'll have to try the sample I added (changing all divs' height instead of the wrapper's one) but if it works you should probably edit your question to mention AdSense